# $m + n$ people are waiting in the line for buying tickets which cost $100$ kn.

Tags: probability

$m + n$ people are waiting in the line for buying tickets which cost $100$ kn. $n$ people have the bill of $100$ kn, and $m$ people a bill of $200$ kn. Each person in line buys one ticket and pays with cash. At the beggining, cashier has no money in cash register. What is the probability of case where nobody has to wait for the rest of his money?

I don't even know how to begin solving this problem. At first glance recursion came to my mind, but I am not allowed to solve it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fulfill the condition the number of people who paid with 100 kn bill should be at any moment larger than or equal to the number of those who paid with 200 kn bill. It is the same as [Bertrand's ballot problem with ties allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem#Variant:_ties_allowed).

Therefore the answer is:
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{n+1-m}{n+1},& n\ge m;\\
0,&n<m.
\end{cases}
$$